# How make icons aside to paragraphs

Tags: html, css

[image]

Anyone know how can i make this texts stay side to the icons? I already try everything..

HTML:

```
<section class="info">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                            <p>
                                <span class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-5x"></span>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elit 
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <span class="fa fa-credit-card fa-5x"></span>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elit
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <span class="fa fa-calendar fa-5x"></span>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elit 
                            </p>
                    </div>
            </section>
```

CSS:

```
.info { 
  background: #f78840;
}
.info .row {
  text-align: justify;
}
.info .row .fa {
  color: black;
  margin: 50px 20px 20px 20px;

}
.info .row p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}
```

I've tried a lot but could not find a solution. Any help is very welcome.

Comment: Change the Html is an option?

Comment: Yes!!! Everything is valid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to float paragraph next to image without wrapping the image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819117/how-to-float-paragraph-next-to-image-without-wrapping-the-image)

Answer (score 0):

```
.row {
position: relative;
}
.fa {
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
}
.row p {
margin-left: 100px; /* width of the icons */
}
```

I have not tried this live but it will give you a start of what you might can do.
Our you could add some more divs around the `<p>`-tags and make them position:relative.

Answer (score 0):

You're already using Bootstrap I think. In that case use its [media object](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media). This makes sure that the text always stays to the right of the image. It might be a quite new addition to Bootstrap however.

For some more background information on the media object see [Stubbornella's blogpost](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/) or [CSS Wizardy's blogpost](http://csswizardry.com/2013/05/the-flag-object/)

Without your CSS it would look like below. Perhaps you need to add an additional class to the span inside the `.media-left` to give it a fixed `width` if you want all icons to take up the same width.

```css
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<section class="info">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <p>
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <span class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-5x"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
            elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elit

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <span class="fa fa-credit-card fa-5x"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
            elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elit
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <span class="fa fa-calendar fa-5x"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elitem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
            elit. Suspendisse in enim ornare nunc mattis congue eu vitae libero. Mauris elit urna, placerat mollis mi consectetur, imperdiet auctor massa. Cras finibus turpis eget elit
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```