# Why Paragraph don't align next to Image in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning frontend web design and i'm trying to build a fully responsive blog like static page.

But my problem is the image are not aligning properly with the paragraph. [image]

As the "Dont Forget to follow Up!" image was supposed to come in the first post content only that is Don't forget to follow Up should be with content What is Lorem Ipsum .. But it's showing up with Where Does it comes from.

My Question is **Why Does This happens ?** workaround i've seen here [How to float paragraph next to image without wrapping the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819117/how-to-float-paragraph-next-to-image-without-wrapping-the-image) but i didn't get this why this problem actually happens.

```css
body {
  background-color: #DCDBD9;
  color: #2C2C2C;
  font: normal 100% Cambria, Georgia, serif;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h1 a {
  color: #747474;
  font: bold 0.45833em Calibri, Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  text-transform: : uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#page {
  margin: 36px auto;
  width: 90%;
}
#nav {
  float: right;
  /*padding: 42px 0 0 30px;*/
}
#nav li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.blog {
  clear: both;
  margin: 50px auto 53px;
  width: 93.75%;
}
.blog .main {
  float: left;
  width: 62.88%;
  /* 566px / 900px */
}
.blog .other {
  float: right;
  width: 36.77%;
  /* 331px / 900px */
}
.lede {
  padding: 0.8em 5.333%;
}
.recent-entries {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 69.788%;
  /* 231 / 331px */
}
.article {
  padding: 40px 8.480%;
}
.date {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -17.088%;
  /* 81px / 474px */
  width: 14.55%;
  /* 69px / 474px */
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0.59%;
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
.date:hover {
  background: #9c3;
}
img,
embed,
object,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.figure {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 2.531%;
  /* 12px / 474px */
  width: 48.734%;
  /* 231px / 474px */
}
h2 {
  color: #F90B6D;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
p {
  color: #222;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!--  <h1> This is the top header! <a href="#"> Read More </a> </h1> -->

<div id="page">

  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">About me</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Stuff</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Junk Stuff</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="blog section">
    <h1 class="lede">Responsive Blog </h1>
    <div class="main">

      <div class="article">
        <div>
          <div class="date">
            1 Sept 2015
          </div>
          <h2> What is Lorem Ipsum ?</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages , and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

          <div class="figure">
            <p>
              <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3hYQ.png" alt="">
              <b class="figcaption">Remember This</b>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="date">
          5 Sept 2015
        </div>
        <h2> Where does it comes from ? </h2>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
          up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
          Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from
          a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original
          form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>


      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/end.main -->
    <div class="other">
      <p>Recent Enteries</p>
      <div class="recent-entries">
        <p>1.Simply First Entry</p>
        <p>2. Simply second Entry</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /end .other -->
  </div>
  <!--/end .blog.section -->
</div>
<!-- /end #page-->
```

Comment: Could you possibly upload the image, via edit your question, and use the link generated as the `img` `src` instead? It just allows us to see, what you see, more clearly.

Comment: @jaunt I uploaded the image :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

floatting element should come first/ahead in code from element in the natural flux.

see *(among others links you can find on search engines)* : https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

```css
body {
  background-color: #DCDBD9;
  color: #2C2C2C;
  font: normal 100% Cambria, Georgia, serif;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h1 a {
  color: #747474;
  font: bold 0.45833em Calibri, Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  text-transform: : uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#page {
  margin: 36px auto;
  width: 90%;
}
#nav {
  float: right;
  /*padding: 42px 0 0 30px;*/
}
#nav li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.blog {
  clear: both;
  margin: 50px auto 53px;
  width: 93.75%;
}
.blog .main {
  float: left;
  width: 62.88%;
  /* 566px / 900px */
}
.blog .other {
  float: right;
  width: 36.77%;
  /* 331px / 900px */
}
.lede {
  padding: 0.8em 5.333%;
}
.recent-entries {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 69.788%;
  /* 231 / 331px */
}
.article {
  padding: 40px 8.480%;
}
.date {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -17.088%;
  /* 81px / 474px */
  width: 14.55%;
  /* 69px / 474px */
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0.59%;
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
.date:hover {
  background: #9c3;
}
img,
embed,
object,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.figure {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 2.531%;
  /* 12px / 474px */
  width: 48.734%;
  /* 231px / 474px */
}
h2 {
  color: #F90B6D;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
p {
  color: #222;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!--  <h1> This is the top header! <a href="#"> Read More </a> </h1> -->

<div id="page">

  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">About me</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Stuff</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Junk Stuff</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="blog section">
    <h1 class="lede">Responsive Blog </h1>
    <div class="main">

      <div class="article">
        <div>
          <div class="date">
            1 Sept 2015
          </div>
          <div class="figure">
            <p>
              <img src="http://dummyimage.com/290x400&text=Dont-Forget-To-Follow-Up" alt="">
              <b class="figcaption">Remember This</b>
            </p>
          </div>
          <h2> What is Lorem Ipsum ?</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages , and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

          
        </div>

        <div class="date">
          5 Sept 2015
        </div>
        <h2> Where does it comes from ? </h2>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
          up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
          Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from
          a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original
          form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>


      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/end.main -->
    <div class="other">
      <p>Recent Enteries</p>
      <div class="recent-entries">
        <p>1.Simply First Entry</p>
        <p>2. Simply second Entry</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /end .other -->
  </div>
  <!--/end .blog.section -->
</div>
<!-- /end #page-->
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer :) But can you just give some insight reasoning why this should comes first what difference does it makes in the way HTML is rendered ?

Comment: @AnkurAnand . floating elements are taken out of the flux to the right or left. if before it stands a non floating elements, it first break the line, else it stands aside as long as it has room. element standing behind in the flux non floating will expand under it, only content will be pushed ( it wraps aside and beneath). if you trigger the layout, it wil stand aside or under if not enough room  see this for better understanding : https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 0):

Each HTML element has got a display value which defines how the element is displayed. This value for most elements is block or inline; block elements always start on a new line and take up the full width available while inline elements stay on the same line and take only the amount of space they need.
`<p>` elements fall within the block elements class while `<img>` elements fall in the inline one.

For further explanations and example take a look here [W3C School - HTML Block and Inline Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)