# How to move this paragraph to the right side of the image

Tags: html, css

[image: here is the picture of it]

I was trying to do an udacity's assignment, i want to move the paragraph to the right of the image please help.
I actually tried putting div tags for each and every block ie heading and image and a paragraph

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div>
    <div class="heading">
        <h1>MY FAVOURITE APP</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div class="data">
            <img src="C:\Users\sreem\Desktop\pix.jpeg" alt="">
            <div>
            <p class="para">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

**style.css**
```

css code for html file

```
img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.heading {
    height: 70px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    color:white;
    background-color:#5AB9BA;
    padding-top: 70px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.para{
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
margin-left: 400px;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Paragraph don't align next to Image in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464735/why-paragraph-dont-align-next-to-image-in-html) and a multitude of same answers found by searching SO.

Answer (score 0):

[Float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float) the image to the left.

```css
img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  float: left; /** float the image to the left **/
}

.heading {
  height: 70px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #5AB9BA;
  padding-top: 70px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.para {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>MY FAVOURITE APP</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="data">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/" alt="">
      <p class="para">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use float property. I gave `float: left;` to `img` tag.

```css
img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.heading {
    height: 70px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    color:white;
    background-color:#5AB9BA;
    padding-top: 70px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.para{
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
margin-left: 400px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div>
    <div class="heading">
        <h1>MY FAVOURITE APP</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div class="data">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="">
            <div>
            <p class="para">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Force image float to left:

```
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;


img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```